# xargs for multiple arguments, each with two inputs

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a script.sh that's just a wget:

`wget https://stuff/$1/$2/etc`

Basically I need, for each time the script is run, to input two arguments $1 and $2, and I need to do this multiple times (I have hundreds of files to download that follow this type of path).

I am familiar on how to use xargs to read a .txt file and input each line into the argument, but I'm not sure how to do this when each line has 2 inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Calling Your Script

By default `xargs` crams as many arguments into each command as possible. It does *not* matter whether those arguments are in the same line or in different lines.

You can limit the number of arguments per command using `-n`

```
xargs -n 2 yourWgetScript.sh < yourFile
```

Alternatively, if the file lists the arguments for each call in a single line, you can instruct `xargs` to execute a new command every line instead of every two arguments

```
xargs -L 1 yourWgetScript.sh < yourFile
```

If your file is of the form

```
cmd1-arg1 cmd1-arg2
cmd2-arg1 cmd2-arg2
cmd3-arg1 cmd3-arg2
...
```

and there are no trailing spaces, special symbols, and so on, then those two commands are equivalent. But keep in mind that `xargs` has its own escaping mechanisms. If some of the arguments contain spaces or `\"'` you have to escape them using `\`.

#### More Efficient Alternative

It might be faster to use the following script instead of `xargs yourWgetScript` since the latter repeatedly starts a shell *and* a `wget` process for *each* URL which can be very slow.

```
awk '{print "https://stuff/" $1 "/" $2 "/etc"}' yourFile | xargs wget
```

Comment: So in the case of ```xargs -n 2``` I would have my file as $1 in first line, $2 in second line, $1 in the third line, $2 fourth, and so on, correct? Whereas with ```-L 1``` I can put $1 and $2 in the same line. While using awk, how would my file look like?

Comment: With `-n 2` you **could** have `$1` and `$2` in different lines, but it is **not necessary**. It would be even fine to have one line with thousands of args in it; or one line with one arg, then one line with two args, then one line with three args, and so on. ¶ For `-L 1` and `awk` the args `$1` and `$2` **must** always be in the same line. For these two solutions each line needs exactly two args.